# How do I write an Android Application Record (AAR) using phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I'm using [chariot solutions phonegap plugin](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) to write NFC tags but I'm not sure how to write an [Android Application Record](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createApplicationRecord%28java.lang.String%29) using the phonegap plugin.

Here is my code on how I write an NDEF record:

```js
nfc.addNdefListener( function(nfcEvent) {

    var tag = nfcEvent.tag, ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

    if (tag.isWritable && tag.canMakeReadOnly) {
        log( JSON.stringify( tag ) );

        var type = "application/com.example.name",
        id = 1234,
        payload = nfc.stringToBytes( JSON.stringify( { payloadID : 1234 } ) ),
        record = ndef.record( ndef.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, type, id, payload );

        var message = [ record ];

        nfc.write( message, function() {
            alert( "Successfully written to NFC Tag!" )
        }, function() {
            alert( "Failed to write to NFC Tag!" )
        } );
    }

}, function() { // success callback
    log( "Waiting for NDEF tag" );
}, function(error) { // error callback
    alert( "Error adding NDEF listener " + JSON.stringify( error ) );
} );
```

How do I write an Android Application Record (AAR) using phonegap ?

Comment: Just found this https://plus.google.com/+JanBrands/posts/8n3x9JFnG8T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to write an TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE record based on the [spec found here](https://plus.google.com/+JanBrands/posts/8n3x9JFnG8T)

```js
nfc.addNdefListener( function(nfcEvent) {

    var tag = nfcEvent.tag, ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

    if (tag.isWritable && tag.canMakeReadOnly) {
        log( JSON.stringify( tag ) );

        var type = "application/com.example.name",
        id = 1234,
        payload = nfc.stringToBytes( JSON.stringify( { payloadID : 1234 } ) ),
        mime = ndef.record( ndef.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, type, id, payload );

        var type = "android.com:pkg",
        id = "",
        payload = nfc.stringToBytes( "com.example.name" ),
        aar = ndef.record( ndef.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, type, id, payload);

        var message = [ mime, aar ];

        nfc.write( message, function() {
            alert( "Successfully written to NFC Tag!" )
        }, function() {
            alert( "Failed to write to NFC Tag!" )
        } );
    }

}, function() { // success callback
    log( "Waiting for NDEF tag" );
}, function(error) { // error callback
    alert( "Error adding NDEF listener " + JSON.stringify( error ) );
} );
```

Comment: record id should be a byte array or simply "[]" if you're not using and id.